# jQuery find within each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just a quick jquery question. I have a form with a number of form-groups in it. I need to iterate over the form-groups, and find a particular element in each one. The form-groups consist of 4 input/select elements, each with a different name:

```
dialog.find(".form-group").each((index) => {
console.log($(this).find("input[name='active']"));
    if ($(this).find("input[name='active']").checked) {
        console.log("FOO");
    }
})
```

dialog definitely exists, and it can certainly find form-group objects, but running `.find("input[name='active'].val()")` consistently returns undefined.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to locate with this `.val()` inside the selector?

Comment: Sorry @jom, I've removed the val(), it was a mistake. The issue persists, though.

Comment: So which particular element are you finding, ones that have "active" as name and are checked?

Comment: Yes, it should find an input element with the name 'active' within each of the form-groups. It should then run an if statement on those elements. (There is only one element with the name 'active' in each form-group)

Comment: Might be the same issue like I pointed out [here](/a/54427438/3634538) on another post.

Comment: So when you do `this` inside of this arrow function `.each()`, it's actually referring to the parent element instead of really "each" of the individual `form-group`s.

Comment: That seems to be it, yes. Thank you. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Add a snippet to your question with some markup